# grep: search multiple files

Tags: c, linux, search, grep

I wrote a program (`grep`) that does a search in several files

I would like you to help me get rid of the following warnings I receive when I run with `make`[image]. What should I change?

code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

void grep_function(char *path, char *pattern)
{
    struct stat statbuf;
    if(lstat(path, &statbuf) == 0) 
    {
        if(S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode))
        {
            char buf[255];
            snprintf(buf,255,"grep: %s: Is a directory\n",path);
            write(2,buf,strlen(buf));
            return;
        }
    }
    int fd = open(path,O_RDONLY);
    if(fd<0)
        {     
            char buf[255];
            snprintf(buf,255,"File %s does not exist or is invalid\n",path);
            write(2,buf,strlen(buf));
            return;
        }
    int size=lseek(fd,0,SEEK_END);
    lseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET);
    char c;
    int k=0;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            read(fd,&c,1);
            k++;
            if(c=='\n')
                {
                    char *sir = malloc((k+1)*sizeof(char));
                    lseek(fd,-k,SEEK_CUR);
                    read(fd,sir,k-1);
                    sir[k-1]='\0';
                    char *ret;
                    ret = strstr(sir, pattern);
                    if(ret!=NULL)
                        printf("%s:%s\n",path,sir);
                    free(sir);
                    lseek(fd,i+1,SEEK_SET);
                    k=0;
                }

        }
    if(k!=0)
    {
        char *sir = malloc((k+1)*sizeof(char));
        lseek(fd,-k,SEEK_CUR);
        read(fd,sir,k);
        sir[k]='\0';
        char *ret;
        ret = strstr(sir, pattern);
            if(ret!=NULL)
                printf("%s:%s\n",path,sir);
        free(sir);
    }
    close(fd);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv )
{
    if(argc<3)
        {
            printf("Invalid number of parameters!\n");
            return 1;
        }
    for(int i=2; i<argc; i++)
        {
            grep_function(argv[i],argv[1]);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you ignoring the return value of read?

Comment: And why are you doing `int size=lseek(fd,0,SEEK_END);`?  You just called `lstat()` for the file - it's size is in `statbuf.st_size`.  (Well, the size the file **was** when you checked, anyway...)

Comment: You should call `lseek` zero times for this.  Do *not* try to check the size of the file; just read data until the stream is exhausted.  And stop reading one char at a time!  Read some multiple of BUFSIZ.  (Better yet, use `fread`)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of plain text error messages.  Post the text of the messages as plain text, with `\`\`\`none` on a line of its own before the error messages and `\`\`\`` on a line of its own after the messages (no indentation needed).

Answer (score 2):

[`write()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) returns a value, which is the number of characters written.  You are being warned that you are ignoring potentially valuable information.  You can cast it to void to silence it if you really don't care (`(void)write(...)`).  Similarly with
[`read()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html).

If you are unsure of the reasons why `write` might return less than the specified number of bytes, check the docs.